# Graphing with Loops in R

Tags: r, loops, histogram, graphing

I'm trying to use a loop to graph histograms based on a condition (class(variable)='numeric'), but I'm not getting any output and I'm not sure why.

Code:

```
for (i in length(df)){
  if (class(df[,i])=="numeric"){
   hist(df[,i])
  }
}
```

hist(df[,15]) returns a histogram, and class(df[,15]) = 'numeric',  so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please share it. I cannot reproduce. If I replace `df` in your code with `mtcars` I get 11 histograms. Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: That said, I would recommend using `is.numeric(df[, i])` instead of `class(df[,i])=="numeric"`. It will be more robust.

Comment: In your first line of code you likely mean for (i in 1:length(df)){.  As this code stands it will only do the last graph.

Comment: Gregor, I wasn't getting an error, just no output. Lucy figured it out it was a typo— i in length(df) should have been i in 1:length(df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just have a small typo - it should be `for (i in 1:length(df))` rather then just `length(df)` (the latter will only produce a single plot for the last column). Here is a quick example:

```
df <- ChickWeight
for (i in 1:length(df)){
  if (is.numeric(df[, i])) {
   hist(df[, i])
  }
}
```

Edit: Just saw that @Richard Lusch already commented this while I was typing out the answer (I hate when that happens!) If you want to post yours as an answer, I can delete mine!